# The probability of a probability to occur

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering for so long about a problem that i haven't found a solution for yet, That is.
Let's suppose that we have an event (E)
that has a chance of 50% to occur (and 50% not to occur).
Let's take P(E) (50% that the event (E) will occur). And suppose that we know some **True** variables in this section (P(E)) are existing and thus. 
P(E)>=P(E)[bar].
{For more details.
We have for example

- an event that:player1 wins against player2 
  Let's call this event (G)
  The probability of (G) with respect to P1 and P2 is, P(G)=0.5=50%.
- in fact. We know that the P1 has trained alot and P2 has (for example) a broken leg.
  Certainly.
  P(G) will be for sure more than P(G)[bar]. }
  P(x)[bar] is the inverse of P(X)
  ... do you think i am right ? If so. Does it have a formula to calculate it (the real probability i call it) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a *conditional probability*. We would say that we are seeking the "probability of event G **given** P1 has practiced hard and P2 has a broken leg." Mathematically, this conditional probability is written $\mathbb{P}(G|\mbox{P1 practised and P2 has a broken leg})$. This is generally computable by the definition,

$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A,B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$,

Although you may not know the values in the above equation in which case you can't compute the probability and should probably try to estimate it from real life observations.

Comment: Oww that's it. Thanks :)

Comment: @xygo no problem, if this answers your question feel free to mark it as a satisfactory answer. If not, feel free to discuss it further.

Comment: Yeah thanks it was very satisfying